# Hashicorp Vault - Permission denied in API While Succcess In CLI

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I'm running a PoC with HCP Vault.
I created an admin token. I logged in from my computer. Developed a policy with reading permission to a simple KV secret. I generated a token from the policy.

With the same token in the CLI I manage to get the secret. I try to fetch the data from the REST API but I receive 403.

Note: When I run Vault in dev mode locally both methods work

```
❯ vault token create -policy=my-spring-boot-app-policy
Key                  Value
---                  -----
token                hvs.XXX
token_accessor       AAA
token_duration       1h
token_renewable      true
token_policies       ["default" "my-spring-boot-app-policy"]
identity_policies    []
policies             ["default" "my-spring-boot-app-policy"]

❯ vault login hvs.XXX
Success! You are now authenticated. The token information displayed below
is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login"
again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.

Key                  Value
---                  -----
token                hvs.XXX
token_accessor       AAA
token_duration       59m44s
token_renewable      true
token_policies       ["default" "my-spring-boot-app-policy"]
identity_policies    []
policies             ["default" "my-spring-boot-app-policy"]

❯ curl --header "X-Vault-Token: hvs.XXX" --request GET https://vault-cluster-public-vault-XXX.YYY.z1.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/secret/data/my-spring-boot-app | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    60  100    60    0     0    125      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   127
{
  "errors": [
    "1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"
  ]
}
```

CLI

```
❯ vault kv get secret/my-spring-boot-app
========= Secret Path =========
secret/data/my-spring-boot-app

======= Metadata =======
Key                Value
---                -----
created_time       2022-09-15T14:03:22.327127967Z
custom_metadata    <nil>
deletion_time      n/a
destroyed          false
version            5

======= Data =======
Key            Value
---            -----
hello.world    Bye from Vault
mykey          Vault Key
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a response from HCP Vault you need to add the header **X-Vault-Namespace** with the value **admin**.

For example:

```
❯ curl --header "X-Vault-Token: hvs.XXX" --header "X-Vault-Namespace: admin" --request GET https://vault-cluster-public-vault-AAA.BBB.z1.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/secret/data/my-spring-boot-app | jq
```

I found the reference in https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.namespaces